# Github like diff view for TFS

Tags: tfs, diff, changeset

I've been looking through the web and here on SO for a tool and/or native way to have my TFS server show me all the diff of the files in a changeset in 1 overview much like Github does. Unfortunately I've been unable to locate any useful information. Can anyone point me in the direction of such a thing or is the only solution to code my own VS-TFS plugin for this purpose?

For those that don't know how it looks on github:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of TFS are you using?  The hosted version of TFS recently got this feature.  Check out tfs.visualstudio.com and create an account.  The changeset view offers similar functionality to what GitHub offers.

tfs.visualstudio.com also recently launched hosted Git repositories so you could store all of your code in one place if you are looking to do that.

Comment: I'm using an on site TFS server so I'm afraid that this won't help me.

Comment: What version is your on-premises TFS server?  TFS 2012 Update 2 will be coming out soon and will contain this view.  If you can upgrade your server to that version you will be able to make use of the feature.

Comment: Sadly it's still a TFS2010, it's good to hear that it'll become a native view soon however.